# How do I find the address of a array which is <value optimized out>?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, gdb

For now, I can not disable the optimization with GCC.

Do it exist some tools like objdump, readelf etc. which can help me to find the address of the array which is value optimized out?

If I success, I can use the GDB to dump the value in the array.

Comment: By reading Assembly code.

Comment: If the array has been optimized out then it may not exist in code any more, e.g. when compiled with `gcc` / `-O3` `array` doesn't exist in the output code for the following TU and `test` effectively becomes `return 5;`: `static int array[2000] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; int test(void) { return array[4]; }`

Answer (score 1):

If it's a static array you could use a map file: have gcc generate it (using -Wl,-Map,mymapfile.map) and look up the address (not familiar with gcc map files, but that address is normally relative to the address where the binary is loaded). Else if it's allocated on the heap, use a breakpoint in malloc, check when it gets called with the size of the array you're after and check the pointer it returns. Or in both cases, as Alex points out in the comment: check the address in disassembly.